# Select Unique Model Attributes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model `list`, which has attributes `name` and `id`.

I want to select every unique `name` attribute across all `list` models.

So if my list models look like this:

```
list1

id: 1
name: ABC
```

---

```
list2

id:2
name: DEF
```

---

```
list3

id:3
name: ABC
```

I want to end up with an array like so ['ABC','DEF']. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with

```
List.select(:name).distinct
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for more information about the `ActiveRecord` query interface.